# How can I replace a model that has an armature with another nearly identical object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, bones

I have an armature that is not subdivide or solidify-friendly (the faces have some inconsistencies) so i would like to import the parts of the model (sandals, legs, jacket etc.) and import them as separate objects into an online STL repair website to fix them (*In their T pose rest positions*), and then import the fixed model parts back into blender to replace the old model parts. I would like them to attach to the armature the same way to old model did.
Ive tried just parenting the object to the bone but the object gets a weird stretch in the wrong places. I'm looking for a more exact replacement method.

Picture of the model part i want to replace (in Blue) next to the fixed (also thickened) object in green:

So is there a way to perfectly replace an object attached to an armature with another object, keeping the same armature functions?

I have an armature that is not subdivide or solidify-friendly (the faces have some inconsistencies) so i imported separated parts of the model into an online STL repair website to fix them (*In their T pose rest positions*), and i would like to then import the fixed model parts back into blender to use them to replace the old model parts. I would like them to attach to the armature the same way to old model did.

Ive tried just parenting the object to the bone with automatic weights but the object gets a weird stretch in the wrong places. I’m looking for a more exact replacement method.

Issue pictured below:

[image: Issue Stretch]
￼

The original pose:

[image]

Picture of the model i want to replace next to the newly fixed (also thickened) model:

[image: Picture of the model i want to replace next to the newly fixed (also thickened) model:]

So is there a way to perfectly replace an object attached to an armature with another object(s), keeping the same armature functions?

Comment: maybe look into the Data Transfer modifier and apply it?